# Как перегрузить оператор умножения на число?

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать класс матрицы, нужно дать возможность умножать матрицу на число

```
template<typename type = double>
class Test {
    type i;

public:
    Test(type _i) {
        i = _i;
    }


    Test<type> operator * (type val) const {
        Test<type> t(val * i);
        return t;
    }
};



int main() {
    Test<> test(1);

    Test<> test2 = 3.0 * test;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы перегрузили оператор умножения функцией-членом, которая будет использоваться только в таких ситуациях как

```
Test<> test2 = test * 3.0;
```

То есть ваш оператор - это именно оператор умножения *матрицы на число*, а не оператор умножения *числа на матрицу*. В вашем варианте выражения ваш оператор неприменим.

Пишите еще один оператор для случая, когда *первый* операнд имеет тип `double`. Такой оператор невозможно реализовать функций-членом, а только отдельностоящей функцией.

```
template <typename type>
Test<type> operator *(type lhs, const Test<type> &rhs)
{
  ...
}
```

(Этот вариант перегрузки оператора зачастую называют "перегрузкой friend-функцией", хотя friend-овость здесь никакой прямой роли не играет.)

Для симметрии стоит на самом деле реализовать оба варианта оператора отдельностоящими функциями. И вообще стоит взять в привычку *в первую очередь* всегда рассматривать вариант перегрузки арифметических операторов отдельностоящими функциями, и только в тех случаях, когда это невозможно/неуместно использовать перегрузку функцией-членом.

Также в вашем коде в данный момент присутствует возможность неявной конвертации скаляра типа `type` к матрице типа `Test<type>`. Это может привести к неожиданностям. Если вы не хотите неявной конвертации скаляра к матрице, объявите ваш конвертирующий конструктор как `explicit`.

Comment: Спасибо, про explicit вообще не знал. А можете подсказать ещё одну делать? В std вектор можно инициализировать так `vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};` Как мне тоже научить мой класс принимать конструкцию типо `{1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: @Fangog: Это реализуется через конструктор, принимающий на вход параметр типа `std::initializer_list<type>`. Функциональность доступна начиная с С++11.